# Amasty Sorting Install Issue

Tags: amasty

I got an issue with Amasty Improved Sorting module. Ijust purchased the module and downloaded it.Then, I just placed the module in app/code/Amasty folder and run command:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 and I got the following error.

[image]

They provided me a patch for etc/mview.xml file. Some classnames are mismatched in this file. When I applied that patch and ran the command again, same error occurred.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? Because I have the same issue. if you got any solution, please answer this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this issue occurs in Magento when you install extension having indexer

first find the module in which the indexer `amasty_sorting_bestseller` is available

then run

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_ModuleName
```

then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```